# Android: Decrypt and load a PDF without writing it on disk

Tags: android, encryption, aes

I have some PDF files on the server, those files are encrypted using AES. Using an API call, I get the file-URL and the corresponding decryption key. Then I download the encrypted file. Now I need to decrypt the file using the key and need to show it in a PDF-renderer (i will use any pdf library, though I haven't decided the library yet). Now my question is, how can I decrypt the file without writing/saving the decrypted file to disk? The target is: the decrypted file should be only on RAM, so that no other cannot get the file without using the app. The risk is, if I write the decrypted file to disk, someone can connect the device to PC and can save the file. I want to decrypt it only on RAM and want to load/show the file from RAM. So that when anyone leaves the app, the decrypted file no longer exists.

Comment: Decrypting in ram is no problem. But then using a different app to show the pdf from ram is not possible.

Comment: @greenapps, why cant it be done using content providers?

Comment: Indeed. You can write a content provider for it.

Comment: A good PDF *library* should be able to accept a stream or binary blob that resides in RAM. If it uses a stream you could use `CipherInputStream`.

Comment: @greenapps, I want to use the in-memory pdf in my own app, not in different app.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, can I pass the CipherInputStream directly to the PDF-Viewer? Any idea?

Comment: Hmm, not with the default renderer you can't. It seems it requires a seekable input stream linked to a file descriptor (it specifies this in the API). That's something that I didn't take into account: that the information in the PDF stream may not be needed in that particular order.

Comment: @MdTarikMahmud what approach did you end up taking?